# ¿Qué significa poner ? dentro de un printf en c?

Tags: c

No sé que significa o hace el carácter ? dentro de un printf en c. Por ejemplo:

```
 int main(void)
{
 char cadena[TAM];
printf("\nIntroduce la palabra\n");
gets(cadena);
printf("La palabra: %s %s palindroma.\n",cadena,
(Palindroma(cadena)) ? "es" : "no es");
return 0;
}
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme a entenderlo, el símbolo ? está dentro del printf del main, tampoco sé que significa los : entre es y no es.

Comment: No importa si está o no dentro de un `printf()` es una _expresión_ que puedes utilizar en cualquier otro lugar (también en una asignación, por ejemplo) que hace uso del [operador ternario](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_ternario) que es una forma de escribir una expresión cuyo resultado dependa de una condición. La forma general es `(condicion)?valor1:valor2`. Si la condición es cierta, el resultado de la expresión será `valor1` y si es falsa será `valor2`. En este caso ese resultado es lo que se pasa a `printf()` como parámetro.

Answer (score 3):

> No sé que significa o hace el carácter ? dentro de un printf en c

Ese caracter da igual que esté o no dentro de un `printf`. Te has encontrado con el operador condicional o condicional ternario, el cual tiene esta forma:

```
condicion ? accion_si_true : accion_si_false
```

Este condicional tiene sus peculiaridades respecto al `if` tradicional. A modo de ejemplo, el código de tu pregunta luciría diferente si usásemos el `if` tradicional:

```
char const* temp;
if( Palindroma(cadena) )
  temp = "es";
else
  temp = "no es";

printf("La palabra: %s %s palindroma.\n",cadena,temp);
```

En este caso vemos como el condicional ternario nos permite decidir qué cadena utilizar "*al vuelo*", es decir, sin usar variables intermedias.

Answer (score 2):

El `?` se esta usando como **operador condicional**. Es decir, esta evaluando que la condición, en este caso de método: `Palindroma()` sea `true`.
Y los `:` funciona como un `if-else`. El `"es"` seria que el metodo esta devolviendo un `true` y el `"no es"` es por que devuelve un `false`.

Es una forma simplificada de utilizar un `if-else`, para que lo entiendas mejor.

Si quieres informarte mejor del tema, te dejo un enlace donde te lo explica con detenimiento. Esta usando de ejemplo **C#**, pero viene siendo lo mismo:

[Información Adicional](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Answer (score 2):

Primero debes entender el concepto de llamar a una función:

```
función(parámetro 1, parámetro 2, …, parámetro n)
{
    // Hacer cosas…
}
```

Cuando una función es llamada, se le pasan argumentos:

```
función(argumento 1, argumento 2, …, argumento n);
```

Un argumento de función puede ser un [literal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/279746/2742) o una expresión:

```
función(1 + 2, argumento 2, …, 3 + 4);
//      ^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^
//          \        \            \__ expresión
//           \        \____ literal
//            \__ expresión
```

Cuando la función es llamada, dentro se reciben los valores de las expresiones ya calculadas, así que en el ejemplo anterior `función` recibirá como argumentos `3` y `7` como primer y último parámetros.

Ahora veamos tu caso:

```
printf("La palabra: %s %s palindroma.\n", cadena, (Palindroma(cadena)) ? "es" : "no es");
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//          \                               \                          \__ expresión
//           \                               \____ variable
//            \__ literal de texto
```

Antes de llamar a `printf` se calcula la expresión `(Palindroma(cadena)) ? "es" : "no es"` en el tercer argumento; así que técnicamente no hay ningún `?` dentro del `printf`.

El interrogante (`?`) forma parte de una expresión que forma un [*operador ternario*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_ternario#C++), esta expresión puede aparecer en cualquier parte del código en que esté permitida una expresión.

Answer (score 1):

> > ¿Qué significa poner ? dentro de un printf en c?

El operador ternario es una abreviación de la sentencia `if-else`.

Por ejemplo, tu código sería equivalente a esto:

```
int main(void)
{
    char cadena[TAM];
    printf("\nIntroduce la palabra\n");
    gets(cadena);
    if(Palindroma(cadena))//Esto es equivalente a Palindroma(cadena) != 0
    {
        printf("La palabra: %s es palindroma.\n", cadena);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("La palabra: %s no es palindroma.\n", cadena);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

En estos casos se suele usar el operador ternario para ahorrarnos unas cuantas líneas.

También hay otra forma de escribir tu código con el operador ternario:

```
int main(void)
{
    char cadena[TAM];
    printf("\nIntroduce la palabra\n");
    gets(cadena);
    //Si la función retorna 1, le pasa al parámetro de printf la primera cadena, de lo contrario, pasa la segunda.
    printf((Palindroma(cadena) ? ("La palabra %s es palindroma") : ("La palabra %s no es palindroma")), cadena);
    return 0;
}
```

Si te das cuenta, los dos códigos que he escrito, hacen exactamente lo mismo.

Por último, no uses la función `gets` para leer cadenas, esto puede ocasionar desbordamiento de búfer o incluso bloquear tu programa (para más información: [Por qué no debemos utilizar gets()](https://poesiabinaria.net/2010/04/por-que-no-debemos-utilizar-gets/)).

En su lugar, usa `fgets`, esta función si permite agregar el tamaño del búfer y evita el posible desbordamiento.

```
int main(void)
{
    char cadena[TAM];
    printf("\nIntroduce la palabra\n");
    //sizeof devuelve el tamaño del arreglo cadena
    fgets(cadena, sizeof cadena, stdin);
    printf("La palabra: %s %s palindroma.\n",cadena, (Palindroma(cadena)) ? "es" : "no es");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El simbolo '?' se utiliza para simplificar, viene a ser lo mismo que poner un 'if', son para casos en el que se quiera poner en una misma linea una sentencia 'if' o dentro de una función, cómo en este caso, para delimitar entre 1 o varias opciones según la manera en la que la construllas.

Por ejemplo en este caso, segun lo que devuelva la función 'Palindroma(cadena)' si es 'true' mostrara "es" y si es 'false' mostrará "no es".