# Realizar sumas de binario con Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, redes, binario

me encuentro realizando un app con flutter, una **Calculadora de Subneteo de Redes con la técnica FLSM**, y en el proceso se manejan muchos números binarios, pero al momento de querer realizar una operación entre binarios, no logré hallar una forma directa de hacerlo con Dart, a continuación les muestro un pequeño ejemplo de como lo intenté hacer:

```dart
void main() {
  var a = 00011111;
  var b = 31;
  var c = '00011111';

  var testA = a + 1;
  var testB = b + 1;
  var testC = int.parse(c, radix: 2) + 1;

  var binA = BigInt.from(testA).toUnsigned(8).toRadixString(2).padLeft(8, "0");
  var binB = BigInt.from(testB).toUnsigned(8).toRadixString(2).padLeft(8, "0");
  var binC = BigInt.from(testC).toUnsigned(8).toRadixString(2).padLeft(8, "0");

  print('test A: ' + testA.toString() + '\tbinary: ' + binA);
  print('test B: ' + testB.toString() + '\tbinary: ' + binB);
  print('test C: ' + testC.toString() + '\tbinary: ' + binC);
}
```

La operación es simplemente sumar uno al valor inicial, pero hacerlo en binario, y devolver el resultado en binario igualmente, este es el resultado del algoritmo:

[image: Muestra los resultados del test]
.

Como se muestra, la forma A está descartada, asume el binario como un decimal y continúa con la suma, la forma B y C llegan al resultado pero ambos también requieren del número convertido en decimal para realizar la operación y luego volver a convertirlo en binario.

Actualmente utilizo el método C ya que cuento con los valores en binario, sin embargo me gustaría saber como se pueden realizar operaciones entre binarios con Dart, que tipo de variable se utiliza o si no existe ninguna, o si se puede simular utilizando listas o algo similar, de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Estás teniendo una confusión con los valores [literales](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/279746/2742) y su valor numérico.

Que un número esté compuesto de ceros y unos no lo hace binario, lo que hace que un número sea binario es su base numérica: cien en base diez 100<sub>10</sub> no tiene el mismo valor que cien en base dos 100<sub>2</sub>.

Cuando escribes un literal numérico, se asume que su base es diez:

```
var a = 00011111;
```

La variable `a` contiene 11111<sub>10</sub> no 11111<sub>2</sub> por lo que al sumar uno no obtienes 100000<sub>2</sub> si no 11112<sub>10</sub>.

---

No he podido ver que en [dart](/questions/tagged/dart) se puedan escribir literales binarios, así que tu única opción es `int.parse`, tal y como haces en tu variable `c`.