# ¿Las variables de una función ocupan un espacio en memoria?

Tags: c++, funciones, paso-por-referencia, memoria

Cuando declaro un entero ocupa un espacio en la memoria cuando declaro una funcion, ¿los valores tambien ocupan un espacio? como el ejemplo de abajo

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void cambiarPor6(int &n){//¿la variable n ocupa un espacio en memoria?
    n = 6;
}

void cambiarPor7(int n){//¿la variable n ocupa un espacio en memoria?
    n = 7;
}

int main(){

    int num1 = 5;
    
    cambiarPor6(num1);

    cout<<num1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cuando te refieres a memoria, ¿Cual memoria? O ¿simplemente que ocupe alguna memoria?. En el ultimo caso, toda variable ocupa algún tipo memoria suponiendo que el compilador no elimina esa variable. Hay distintas memorias y  lo interesante es que la velocidad de las memorias es diferente.

Comment: Como lo comenta @CristobalMontecino , toda varible ocupa memoria cuando es declarada, en este proceso se reserva un espacio de memoria respectivamente al tamaño del dato, pero el uso de estas no requiere más memoria. En el caso de las funciones que usan **parámetros por referencia** no se usa más memoria, debido a que la variable usada ya esta definida y solo se interactua con su valor, mientras que cuando es una función de **parámetros por valor** se genera y almacena una copia del valor de la variable que se envía, por ende se usa más memoria.

Comment: Toda variable ocupa memoria. Tanto si es global como local, también si es un parámetro. Lo que ocurre con los parámetros y variables locales es que la memoria en cuestión se reserva en la pila, que es una estructura que sólo existe mientras la función se ejecuta. Cuando la función termina, la zona de pila en que estaban sus variables y parámetros se libera. En el caso de los parámetros por referencia **también** se usa memoria, pero sólo la necesaria para contener la referencia y no para el dato en sí. La referencia es la dirección en que está el dato y ocupa 4 u 8 bytes según la arquitectura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los valores, en principio, no ocupan espacio en memoria principal como tal, a menos que los guardes en variables, ya sean globales, locales o en memoria dinámica. Pero depende de la configuración del compilador para la plataforma o arquitectura de destino.

Como ejemplo, en una instrucción como la siguiente:

```
int numero = 10;
```

La variable `numero` va a ocupar un espacio en memoria, y dependiendo de del lugar en el que la declares, irá a parar a una zona concreta del mapa de memoria del proceso en cuestión, donde las zonas más importantes son:

- Datos (o `data`): es un segmento con las variables globales o estáticas (y en ocasiones las constantes).
- Pila (o `stack`): para las variables locales no estáticas, incluyendo las variables del `main`.
- Montón (o `heap`): para los bloques de memoria reservados con `malloc` o con `new`.
- Código (o `code`): para las instrucciones del programa.

En general, una instrucción como la anterior va a causar que la variable ocupe un espacio en memoria principal. Pero el valor 10 no siempre lo hará. Como digo, dependerá de la configuración del compilador.

Puede ser que el valor 10 se meta como valor inicial en el espacio de memoria asignado para número, ya que se le asigna en la declaración, y el compilador lo puede traducir como:

```
.data                          // Inicio del segmento de datos
    _numero:    .word    10    // El valor 10 estaría inicialmente en la posición de la variable en el mapa de memoria del proceso
.code                          // Inicio del segmento de código
    # ...                      // Código previo
    lw    $1, _numero(0)       // Se carga el valor de la variable en algún registro del procesador para su uso
    # ...                      // Código posterior
```

Pero puede ocurrir dos situaciones alternativas:

En la primera, el valor 10 puede estar codificado en la propia instrucción (de suma por ejemplo), de tal forma que nunca llega a ocupar espacio como dato en sí mismo, pero sí como parte de una instrucción, según el tipo de formato de instrucción de la arquitectura.

```
.data
    _numero:    .word         // No tiene valor inicial, solo se declara su ancho
.code
    # ...
    lw      $1, _numero(0)    // Se carga la variable en algún registro del procesador
    addi    $1, $1, 10        // Se le suma el valor 10, que está codificado en la propia instrucción de suma
    sw      _numero(0), $1    // En algún momento tras su uso, se guarda el valor del registro en memoria principal
    # ...
```

Otra opción es que el valor 10 puede ocupar una zona propia en memoria, en el segmento `data`, y que se cargue en la variable `número` mediante una instrucción de lectura y una de escritura. Aunque esto no es muy común.

Como nota final, recuerda que los parámetros de las funciones son variables locales a dicha función, por lo que ocupan un espacio en memoria, y en concreto, en la zona de pila del proceso, o del hilo de ejecución, para ser más exacto.

Cuando pasas un dato a una función, lo que ocurre es que el valor del argumento se copia en el espacio de pila asignado para el parámetro.

```
int calcularAlgo(int n);
int numero = 10;
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    calcularAlgo(numero);
    return 0;
}
```

La variable `número`, al ser global, ocupará una zona de memoria en el segmento de datos, y al hacer la llamada a `calcularAlgo`, su valor se copiará en la zona de pila para el parámetro `n` de la función.

Incluso en el paso por referencia, lo que se pasa es una dirección de memoria (un número) que será almacenado en el parámetro de la función, que no es otra cosa que una variable local que guarda una dirección de memoria, que ocupará una zona de la pila y que será destruida al terminar dicha función.

Answer (score 2):

> ¿los valores tambien ocupan un espacio?

Vamos a distinguir entre variable y valor:

```
int n = 5;
    ^   ^
    |   Valor
    Variable
```

Pues bien, un valor es simplemente el estado de una variable, por tanto, **no ocupan espacio**. El espacio lo ocupa una variable y es, por tanto, responsabilidad de dicha variable el garantizar que tiene capacidad suficiente para almacenar un valor dado.

Explicado con enteros... una variable `int` ocupa 32 bits, independientemente de que en dicha variable almacenemos un 1 o el número 2.539.842.

Es decir, el valor almacenado puntualmente en una variable **no afecta** al tamaño que dicha variable ocupa en memoria.

Dicho con ejemplos:

```
int n = 2^31;         // ok, n tiene capacidad para 2^32
char cad[4] = "hola"; // ERROR: hola ocupa 5 bytes (no olvidemos el '\0')
```

Por otro lado, los literales puros (un caracter, un entero, ...) *entran* en una instrucción en ensamblador:

```
mov ax, 1234
#       ~~~~ Literal
```

Sin embargo, las cadenas de caracteres, aun siendo literales, no se corresponden con un literal puro:

- Es una composición realizada a partir de caracteres individuales
- Su tamaño es variable y tan largo como se quiera

Por estas características, no entra en una instrucción en ensamblador y, por tanto, el compilador necesita almacenarlas en otro sitio para poder usarlas en el programa.

Para almacenar cadenas literales, el compilador suele recurrir a regiones de memoria constantes, lo que hace entonces es apuntar la dirección de memoria donde empieza dicho literal y así es como te permite usarlo en tu programa.

Así, por ejemplo, el siguiente código:

```
#include <iostream>

void func()
{
    std::cout << "hola" << 5;
}
```

Genera el siguiente [código ensamblado](https://godbolt.org/z/ZR3VDk):

```
.LC0:
    .string "hola"
func():
    sub     rsp, 8
    mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
    mov     edx, 4
    call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
    mov     esi, 5
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
    add     rsp, 8
    jmp     std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
```

Ahí se ve claramente como la cadena, a diferencia del entero, acaba en una región del programa diferente.

Podemos ver claramente cómo recupera la posición de memoria donde se encuentra dicho literal:

```
    mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
```

Mientras que el entero es capaz de cargarlo directamente:

```
    mov     esi, 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Este tema puede ser muy complicado. Así que primero explicare en el caso de que no exista optimización por parte del compilador, por ejemplo, cuando se compila en un modo debug.

La respuesta es sencilla y es un sí. Toda variable ocupa memoria en el programa final para que pueda ser cambiada.

---

Cuando el compilador optimiza,

1. Como `n` en `cambiarPor7` nunca se ocupa y solo cambia el valor en el interior, el compilador cambia:

```
void cambiarPor7(int n){
    n = 7;
}
```

por, entre comillas,

```
void cambiarPor7(){

}
```

Luego, como esa función no hace nada, cuando llames `cambiarPor7`, optimizador no va a llamar a esa función. Así que no se ocupa memoria en el programa final, pero sí se ocupo memoria en el compilador para poder hacer la optimización.

2. Como `cambiarPor6` es una función muy sencilla, en ves de llamarla, el optimizador cambiara:

```
int main(){

    int num1 = 5;
    
    cambiarPor6(num1);

    cout << num1;

    return 0;
}
```

Por

```
int main(){

    int num1 = 5;
    
    num1 = 6;

    cout << num1;

    return 0;
}
```

Luego, optimizara más y pondrá

```
int main(){
    cout << 6;

    return 0;
}
```

Así que, en este ejemplo, no se ocupa memoria en el programa final.

---

Lo interesante, en tu pregunta, sería preguntarse: ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre pasar por referencia o por valor?.

Si necesitas modificar la variable exterior desde el **interior** de la función, estas obligado a pasarlo por referencia.

En el caso de uso en memoria, pasar por referencia requiere el uso de un registro y una desreferencia cuando se usa, es decir, el procesador necesitara, en promedio, más ciclos del procesador para ocuparlo y registros extras para poder desreferenciar. (Puede que, el procesador al optimizar el microcodigo, todo este en cache, etc, no se pueda medir una diferencia significativa, pero es mejor evitar la complejidad)

Asi que, **si solo vas a pasar valores que pueden entrar en un registro, es siempre mejor pasar por valor**. (A menos que estés obligado a usar referencias).

En el caso de que quieras ocupar el valor, es mejor `int` que `&int`. En caso de que quieras modificar estas obligado a usar `&int` o que la función retorne el nuevo valor y se asigne afuera.

Los tipos que no sean estructuras u objetos pueden entrar en un registro. Por ejemplo, `int`, `char`, `long`, etc. Hay objetos y estructuras que también pueden entrar en un registro pero dependen de que su tamaño sea menor o igual al tamaño máximo de los registros. Por ejemplo, si el procesador es de 64 bits, pueden entrar en un registro todos los valores que ocupen a lo sumo 64 bits. Sin embargo, pueden que entren aún teniendo un valor mayor a 64 bits, pero eso depende de que compilador/optimizador use más de un solo registro, que pueda usar registros para vectores, etc. En estos ultimos casos, hay que analizarlo teniendo un código en concreto, no hay una regla general.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> void cambiarPor6(int &n){//¿la variable n ocupa un espacio en memoria?
>     n = 6;
> }
>
> void cambiarPor7(int n){//¿la variable n ocupa un espacio en memoria?
>     n = 7;
> }
> ```

Si y si. En ambos casos. Escribir valores en memoria es como escribir en una pizarra:

[image]

Para que un valor pueda ser leído, tiene que estar escrito en la pizarra; pero lo que ocupa espacio no es el valor, el valor es un concepto (lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/279746/2742) para saber más) lo que ocupa espacio es la variable que lo guarda que, siguiendo con la analogía de la pizarra, es la porción de pizarra donde está escrito el valor.